# Payment methods not showing

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I've installed - drupal commerce +  paypal + payment + commerce payment- modules.
Commerce seems to be working fine with regards adding and displaying products.
But in 'configuration', there is no list item there that says 'payment methods'.
I've enabled all related modules, so 'paypal wpp' and '..wps' etc.
Also installed and enabled 'payment' and payment commerce'.
What am I missing?

Any help would be great,thanks
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal Commerce payment  methods can usually be found at      /admin/commerce/config/payment-methods. They are rules in fact. If for any reason that menu doesn't exist, check your rules.

To get that menu you need ro enable Payment UI module.

You also need to properly enable and setup your checkout panes at admin/commerce/config/checkout

Comment: Thanks for your help, paypal WPS was diasbled in rules. I have just enabled it. Also reviewed the checkout settings and everything looks alright-the payment pane is enabled and under the payment part of the checkout. Still no menu item for payment methods though. I'm stumped on this one!

Comment: That's the one! Thanks a lot! I have spent hours scratching my head about this:)